# Android Application - Best Way To Display Calculated Result

Tags: android, textview

I am working on a calculator application for Android. I was wondering what the best option out there is to display the calculated value ? Currently I am displaying result in a `EditText` control.

I was wondering if anything like label control in Android available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there an equivalent control for a label?

Yes. It is equivalent to [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use `TextView`  control in Android which is equivalent to label functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that user to Write Figures from Keyboard also then You should Provide an [EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html).

And if you have only Keyborad for input then Provide a [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html).